# Call a command with arguments in Emacs minibuffer

Tags: emacs, command, interactive

I know that **M-x (execute-extended-command)** allows one to call a command in Emacs by typing its name. That however doesn't allow me to call command with arguments, e.g **"backward-word 5"**

I am aware that **C-5 M-b** produces the desired result but I am looking for a general method.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks,
Danny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@abo-abo provided the general answer: use `M-:`.

1. However, if you are interested not only in obtaining the *side effects* of the evaluation, and not only in a cursory overview of the return value, but in the ***full return value*** (regardless of its size and complexity), then vanilla Emacs `M-:` is not what you want.

   For that, I substitute `pp-eval-expression` for `eval-expression` wrt its key bindings (including `M-:`), and I recommend this practice for others too:

   > (substitute-key-definition 'eval-expression 'pp-eval-expression global-map)

   That *pretty-prints* the return value, and you can make it print the complete value (no ellipses: `...`).
2. In addition, I offer a modified version of `pp-eval-expression` in library [`pp+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/pp%2b.el). It has these advantages:

   - Reads with *completion*, using `pp-read-expression-map`.
   - Emacs-Lisp mode indentation and completion key bindings are available during input.
   - With a prefix arg, inserts the resulting value into the current buffer at point.
   - With a negative prefix arg, if the return value is a string, inserts it into the buffer without double-quotes (`"`).
   - Font-locks the return value (syntax highlighting) for Emacs-Lisp mode.  (And during display `emacs-lisp-mode-hook` and `change-major-mode-hook` are inhibited.)
   - Respects new user options `pp-eval-expression-print-length`,
     `pp-eval-expression-print-level`, and standard option `eval-expression-debug-on-error`. The former are separate from the similar, standard options `eval-expression-print-length` and
     `eval-expression-print-level` because the use cases are typically different.
3. If you use library [***Icicles***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles) then you get the same advantages as library [`pp+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/pp%2b.el) -- no need to load `pp+.el` also.

Answer (score 2):

Eval it: <kbd>M-:</kbd> `(backward-word 5)` <kbd>RET</kbd>.